# How to exactly horizontally center a div inside a body integrating the scrollbar-width?

Tags: html, css, centering

I´m trying to center a div in the center of a body so the margin to the left and the margin to the right (margin to scrollbar) are the same.

This is what I mean:
[Website](http://willwhitehead.com/)
The Top blue header is centered in the middle with same margin left and right.

But when I try to code it myself, the scrollbarwidth is manipulating the margin and sizes...

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100em;
  background-color: aqua;
}

div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Even if I smaller the width it still has not the same margins:

```css
body{
  width: 98%;
  height: 100em;
  background-color: aqua;
}

div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

That kid who created that page above did not seem to use any greater css, so wheres the trick ?

Comment: set the div within a container and that should fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

This is my Answer to my own Question, I'm not sure if it should be used likes this but I just removed the `100% width` from the body.

No idea why css acts like this but I checked that websites source and it did not has any body width so I just tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport widths instead of percentage and set margins like this:

```
body {width:100vw}
div {margin:0 auto}
```